# Divide a dataset into two clusters, with equal total variances

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, partitioning, variance, centroid

I have a data set, which consists of a number of elements -- divided into two distinct categories (with an equal number of elements for each category) -- and with two continuous variables describing them, like so:

```
ID  |  Category  |  Variable_1  |  Variable_2
--------------------------------------------
1   |  Triangle  |  4.3522      |  5.2321
2   |  Triangle  |  3.6423      |  6.3223
3   |  Circle    |  5.2331      |  3.2452
4   |  Circle    |  2.6334      |  7.3443
... |  ...       |  ...         |  ...
```

Now, I would like to divide my dataset into two new sets that match as closely as possible with regard to where the mean of the individual sets lies in the 2D space that is defined by `Variable_1` and `Variable_2`. That is, the distance between the two sets should be as close as possible.

Further, if possible (since I understand that this might make the problem much more complicated to solve), I would like the variances within the two sets to match as closely as possible, where we, for example, can define the variance of a whole set as the sum of the variances of each variable. Here I'm thinking that you just add another dimension in your space for the variance and try to find the best solution for the whole 3D space that is consisted by the two variables and the variance.

How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: Sounds like you really want **clustering**. Specifically into 2 clusters. But your equal-total-variances metric is nonstandard. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: @speldosa  Respectfully, I think k-means would not work on this occasion. The 2 centroids will practically be the two samples' means and those obviously cannot be the same because otherwise we would not have 2 clusters. The centroids are best if they are as far away as possible from each other. You can check [here](http://home.deib.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/kmeans.html) too. P.S. I am always open for discussion :)

Comment: @smci Sorry the above message was directed to you and not speldosa :). Sorry about that.

Comment: I specifically said K-means was not the type of clustering OP wants, I was just trying to point them to the vocabulary to help them articulate what they **do** want. (Do they want to split into 2 clusters and heuristically move the centroid around until total variance is roughly equal?? or what?) Might be more on-topic at stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The way I would try to approach this problem would be (as you mention above) to care about the distance between variable1 and variable2. 
I would therefore create a new field called distance (below I named it diff) which will be calculated as variable1-variable2. I would then order the dataframe by that column and split the dataframe row by row, i.e every odd row would go to pot1 and every even row would go to pot2. This is demonstrated with the following code as an example:

```
id<-1:2000
a<-runif(2000,-100,100)
b<-runif(2000,-200,200)
mydf <- data.frame(id,a,b)

mydf['diff'] <- mydf[['a']] - mydf[['b']]
mydf<-mydf[with(mydf, order(diff)), ]

head(mydf,20)
```

output:

```
> head(mydf,20) #as you can see the dataframe is ordered by diff (ascending)
       id         a        b      diff
1732 1732 -95.96522 198.1666 -294.1318
187   187 -94.24905 196.9341 -291.1831
338   338 -95.31069 194.9997 -290.3104
231   231 -91.98249 194.0672 -286.0497
1513 1513 -97.01006 183.5874 -280.5974
715   715 -94.53303 185.1026 -279.6356
145   145 -99.73511 178.2460 -277.9811
979   979 -87.73586 190.0489 -277.7848
1165 1165 -85.53447 187.6254 -273.1598
1243 1243 -94.75502 176.8572 -271.6122
1208 1208 -77.32021 189.1589 -266.4791
1826 1826 -92.23949 171.6341 -263.8736
167   167 -98.84123 163.6960 -262.5372
1283 1283 -76.54766 185.8721 -262.4197
1391 1391 -72.04732 189.9422 -261.9896
322   322 -77.53867 183.4744 -261.0131
75     75 -88.04799 171.9066 -259.9546
882   882 -65.11661 193.8533 -258.9699
1119 1119 -77.59978 181.2392 -258.8390
1624 1624 -81.81879 175.9795 -257.7983
```

and now to split the dataframe:

```
samplea_1<-NULL
samplea_2<-NULL
sampleb_1<-NULL
sampleb_2<-NULL
id_1<-NULL
id_2<-NULL
diff_1<-NULL
diff_2<-NULL
for ( i in 1:nrow(mydf) ) {
  if(i%%2==0) {
    samplea_1 <- append(samplea_1,mydf$a[i])
    sampleb_1 <- append(sampleb_1,mydf$b[i])
    id_1      <- append(id_1,mydf$id[i])
    diff_1    <- append(diff_1,mydf$diff[i])
  } else {
    samplea_2 <- append(samplea_2,mydf$a[i])
    sampleb_2 <- append(sampleb_2,mydf$b[i])
    id_2      <- append(id_2,mydf$id[i])
    diff_2    <- append(diff_2,mydf$diff[i])
  }
}

sample1<-data.frame(samplea_1,sampleb_1,id_1,diff_1)
sample2<-data.frame(samplea_2,sampleb_2,id_2,diff_2)
summary(sample1)
summary(sample2)
```

output:

```
> summary(sample1)
   samplea_1          sampleb_1             id_1            diff_1        
 Min.   :-99.2058   Min.   :-199.519   Min.   :   1.0   Min.   :-291.183  
 1st Qu.:-47.5615   1st Qu.:-100.917   1st Qu.: 495.8   1st Qu.:-105.851  
 Median :  1.3997   Median :   7.004   Median : 980.5   Median :  -1.333  
 Mean   :  0.7047   Mean   :   2.044   Mean   : 991.0   Mean   :  -1.340  
 3rd Qu.: 50.4087   3rd Qu.: 101.678   3rd Qu.:1482.8   3rd Qu.:  99.381  
 Max.   : 99.8470   Max.   : 199.833   Max.   :2000.0   Max.   : 291.797  
> summary(sample2)
   samplea_2          sampleb_2              id_2            diff_2        
 Min.   :-99.7351   Min.   :-199.9494   Min.   :   2.0   Min.   :-294.132  
 1st Qu.:-48.4339   1st Qu.: -99.7880   1st Qu.: 509.8   1st Qu.:-106.338  
 Median : -1.4627   Median :   6.8745   Median :1024.0   Median :  -1.425  
 Mean   : -0.7104   Mean   :   0.9099   Mean   :1010.0   Mean   :  -1.620  
 3rd Qu.: 48.1663   3rd Qu.:  94.7360   3rd Qu.:1513.2   3rd Qu.:  99.334  
 Max.   : 99.9496   Max.   : 199.8544   Max.   :1996.0   Max.   : 288.840
```

As you can see the diff columns have almost the same mean which is a bit intuitive because we ordered the dataframe according to that column, but as you can see the same is approximately the same for columns samplea and sampleb! This happens because diff is derived from a and b but the results will be less accurate according to how high the variance is for each individual column a and b.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This would probably do as a back-up solution if I won't come up with anything else. Thanks!